# Compute: binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Compute from Left-Side: 
$$ {2p \choose p} -{2p \choose p-1}  = {(\frac {1}{p+1})} {2p \choose p}$$

This is the answer

$$ ={2p \choose p} -{2p \choose p - 1}$$
$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right)-\left(\frac{(2p)!}{(p-1)! (p+1)!}\right) $$
$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right) \left(1-\frac{p}{p+1}\right) $$
$$={2p \choose p} {\left(\frac {p+1-p}{p+1}\right)} $$
$$={\frac {1}{p+1}} {2p \choose p}$$
$$=RS$$
I'm really trying to understand the algebraic part of this example. Could someone me help understand this problem by breaking it step-by-step?

Especially this part:

$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right) \left(1-\frac{p}{p+1}\right) $$
$$...$$
$$...$$
$$...$$
Thanks

Comment: Note, you have a typo: $=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right) \color{red}{-}\left(\frac{(2p)!}{(p-1)! (p+1)!}\right)$  was missing a minus sign.

Comment: I just edited that minus sign in.

Comment: yesss true! thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ ={2p \choose p} -{2p \choose p - 1}$$
Apply definition of $^nC_r=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.
$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right)-\left(\frac{(2p)!}{(p-1)! (p+1)!}\right) $$
Extra step. Rewrite $(p-1)!$ as $\frac{p!}{p}$ and $(p+1)!$ as $p!(p+1)$.

$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right)-\left(\frac{p(2p)!}{p! p!(p+1)}\right) $$
Take out common factor.
$$=\left(\frac{(2p!)}{(p!) (p!)}\right)\left(1-\frac{p}{p+1}\right) $$
Find common denominator
$$={2p \choose p} {\left(\frac {p+1-p}{p+1}\right)} $$
Simplify
$$={\frac {1}{p+1}} {2p \choose p}$$
Done
$$=RS$$

Comment: so (p-1)! is equivalent to (p!/p)?

Comment: An easier way to see it is to note: $p! = p\times((p-1)!)$

Comment: ohhh i see! Thanks so much Ian :)